# How to convert QGraphicsItem to SVG element in PySide or PyQt?

Tags: qt, svg, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to import SVG as QGraphicsItem in QGraphicsScene and vice versa.

Is there a way to do it with QSvgGenerator, QSvgRenderer or have to build my own method for that.
Also, can't find builtin method for the XML(SVG) representation. Please help.